# Python webbrowser - registering browsers on Windows

Tags: python, browser

I'm trying to register the Firefox browser to run on Windows. According to the documentation for Webbrowser, "If the environment variable BROWSER exists, it is interpreted to override the platform default list of browsers, as a os.pathsep-separated list of browsers to try in order". I tried setting it, but it had no impact.

```
Z:\>SET BROWSER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe %s

Z:\>python3
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (I
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import webbrowser
>>>
>>> webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
True
>>>
```

webbrowser.get("firefox") doesn't work either

How can I make webbrowser launch Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set static envionment viraibles, this you can do in the properties of my computer... Whether or not it will help is for you to figure out (worked over here..).

Another way to do this:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.get("open -a C:\\Program F~\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe %s")
webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
```